# usar .htacces adequadamente para links

Tags: php, apache, php-7

Então, tenho no meu .htaccess a seguinte condição:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.(jpe?g?|png|gif|css|js) [NC]
```

que me diz para liberar as extensões acima no caso do redirecionamento abaixo

```
RewriteRule .* index.php [NC,L]
```

Código completo do .htaccess

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
  # LIGA O MOTOR DE REESCRITA (Rewrite)
  RewriteEngine on
  # BUSCA PELA BASE /crud/ NO HOST ACESSADO
  RewriteBase /crud/
  # FAZ UMA ESCESSÃO DE REDIRECIONAMENTO PARA A PÁGINA manutencao.php CASO O NAVEGADOR RECEBA ELA NA URL
  # PERCEBA O ! ANTES DO NOME DO ARQUIVO. ISSO DIZ AO .htaccess QUE O ARQUIVO EM QUESTÃO NÃO SEGUE A REGRA E ABRE NORMALMENTE
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/manutencao.php$ [NC]
  # FAZ UMA ESCESSÃO E LIBERA IMAGENS NESTA PAGINA
  # NOTE QUE PAR ESAS EXTENSÕES, O REDIRECIONAMENTO NÃO ACONTECE E DÁ ERRO 404 CASO A IMAGEM NÃO EXISTA
  # AS DEMAIS EXTENSÕES SÃO TODAS REENVIADAS PARA A INDEX
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.(jpe?g?|png|gif|css|js) [NC]
  # REENVIA QUALQUER ACESSO AO SITE PARA A PÁGINA index.php NO HOST INDICADO LIBERANDO AS EXCESSÕES ACIMA DESCRITAS
  RewriteRule .* index.php [NC,L]

  ErrorDocument 401 http://localhost/crud/401.php
  ErrorDocument 403 http://localhost/crud/403.php
  ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/crud/404.php
  ErrorDocument 500 http://localhost/crud/500.php

</ifModule>
```

Imagine o caso em que o usuário acesse:

```
http://www.seusite.com.br/pasta/arquivo.php
```

e considere ainda o caso em que o arquivo `arquivo.php` não exista na pasta.

O **redirecionamento** para a **página** `404.php` ocorrerá normalmente; Porém, as **imagens** da **pagina** não abriram tampouco os links de `.css's` e `.js's` abriram por causa do endereços das imens:

404.php

```
<?php
  require_once 'global/erros/erros.ini'; 
  $titulo = "CRUD - Página não encontrada";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <title>CRUD - Página não encontrada</title>
   <?php  require_once("global/meta/meta.ini"); ?>
   <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-png" href="img/favicon.png">
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="global/css/erros.css" />
  </head>
  <body>

     <div class="topo"><h1 class="titulos"><?php echo $titulo; ?></h1></div>
     <div class="naoEncontrada"><?php require_once("404Conteudo.php"); ?></div>
     <div class="final"><?php require_once("public/requeridos/finalErros.php"); ?></div>     

  </body>
</html>
```

404Conteudo.php

```
<a href="http://localhost/crud">
  <img src="img/logoCrud.png" title="Logotipo" class="logotipo"  />
</a>

<h1 class="titulos">Oh não! Página Não Encontrada!</h1>
<p>O que você esperava encontrar não está aqui?</p>

<br /> <br />

<h2>Detalhes:</h2>

<ul>
  <li>A página que Você tentou acessar não existe.</li>
  <li>Data atual: <?php echo date("d/m/Y"); ?></li>
</ul>
```

Notem que os endereços dos **links** e das **imagens** ***NÃO*** são **absolutos**.

Alguma forma de contornar esse **problema** pelo `.htaccess`? Ou terei mesmo que que adicionar **endereços** **absolutos** em todos os arquivos?